# Java enum implements interface with Class<T> return type

Tags: java, generics, enums

OK, be nice.

Here's an enum that implements an interface with a method that returns a 'raw type' which gives me a warning on the `getCaste()` method in the interface.

```
public enum Thing implements HasCaste {

    Type1 {
        @Override
        public Class getCaste() {
            return String.class;
        }
    };
}

interface HasCaste {
    public Class getCaste();
}
```

If I change the interface's method to:

```
public <T> Class<T> getCaste();
```

it changes to an unchecked warning on `Type1`'s method signature. If I then change `Type1.getCaste()`'s signature to:

```
public <T> Class<T> getCaste()
```

then the return has an incompatible types error because `Class<String>` can't be converted to `Class<T>`. If I then change the return to `(Class<T>) String.class`, we get an unchecked cast warning.

Is there a way to do this without a warning?

EDIT:

Sorry I didn't add this in earlier, but it'd be good to do this:

```
  , Type2 {
        @Override
        public Class getCaste() {
            return Integer.class;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234960/java-generics-and-enum-loss-of-template-parameters

Comment: To your edit, you cannot use enum for that.

Comment: @Radiodef I was actually planning on linking that question :p (I'm the asker of that one)

Comment: @Radiodef, That's unfortunate...

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunate, and technically speaking it would actually be possible for enums to carry a generic type so it's just a limitation of the language specification right now. (@EpicPandaForce hi : ) )

Comment: Declaring a method with type `public <T> Class<T> getCaste()` is telling the compiler that the _caller of the method_ can choose any `T` and get back a `Class<T>`.  That's not actually true, though, so you get a warning.

Comment: when in doubt, wildcard :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just leave the type parameter of the returned class unspecified:

```
public enum Thing implements HasCaste {

    Type1 {
        @Override
        public Class<String> getCaste() {
            return String.class;
        }
    }, Type2 {
        @Override
        public Class<Integer> getCaste() {
            return Integer.class;
        }
    };
}

interface HasCaste {
    public Class<?> getCaste();
}
```

Comment: The covariant overrides are not visible, though, because the constant declarations are just `Thing`.

Comment: @Radiodef, how do I test that the overrides are not visible?

Comment: Try an assignment like `Class<String> c = Thing.Type1.getCaste();`. http://ideone.com/ij7EwN

Comment: @Radiodef If I could, would that violate Liskov?

Comment: No, because it still behaves as the supertype (returning a `Class<?>`). The issue here is that the declaration of the enum constant is `Thing`, and so the anonymous subclass where the override is defined is not visible.

Answer (score 2):

As it was determined in the [question I asked a while ago that was linked by Radiodef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234960/java-generics-and-enum-loss-of-template-parameters), you cannot do that with an `enum`, only by a simulated enum that's actually a class, like this.

```
public abstract class Thing<T> implements HasCaste<T> {
    public static final Thing<String> Type1 = new Thing<String>() {
        @Override
        public Class<String> getCaste() {
            return String.class;
        }
    };
    public static final Thing<Integer> Type2 = new Thing<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Class<Integer> getCaste() {
            return Integer.class;
        }
    };

    private Thing() {
    }
}
```

As you can see, that is not an `enum` though. It is not possible with a mere `enum`, because enums cannot have type parameters.

p.s.: If you found this helpful, please look at [Radiodef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28247498/2413303) for a more complete explanation, I learned this from him, after all :)

Comment: The other two answers clearly accomplish the task. Is cannot the right word? Perhaps 'should not' would be better?

Comment: If you try to access `Thing.Type1` in the other two solutions, then you won't get the class as `Class<String>` and Type2 as `Class<Integer`>, you'll get it as `Class<?>` essentially `Class<Object>`.

Comment: ....oh, but if you just wanted to remove the warning, then sure, `Class<?>` works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to define several differently "typed" enum constants, then one could do:

```
interface HasCaste {
    public Class<?> getCaste();
}

public enum Thing implements HasCaste<?> {

    Type1(String.class),
    Type2(Integer.class);

    public final Class<?> clazz;

    private Thing(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getCaste() {
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

One then delays the typing to the future usage of getCaste. The main characteristic of an enum is a closed value domain; one has to list all possible values inside the class.